No business class in American, but on British Airways
I went to book a flight from Boston to London on American Airlines, but it only shows "Premium" and "Premium Economy" seats. The "Premium Economy" seats cost business class price (~$4000) but are just economy seats with extra legroom. I do not see any option for Business class. So I go to British Airways.
British Airways offers the same flight ON AMERICAN in Business Class (meaning a large recliner seat) for $2500.
What's going on here?

Just hypothesis: Holiday period, so not much business passengers, and maybe good time for a revision, so using a normally medium haul (or just continental) plane. Note: contrary to Europe, it seems "America" has a low demand in summer.

What date? What flight? What interface (web, app…)? Note that sometimes on codeshares each airline will have its own quota of seats in different classes on each flight rather than share all seats.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codeshare_agreement#Types_of_code_sharing It’s a bit surprising that AA and BA would be in a block space arrangement, but given the changes AA are making to their booking systems, anything is possible…

Is this a question or just a rant?

@JoErNanO  I don't think it's a rant.  I'd also be generally confused as to why two operators can offer totally different options on the same flight.

Note also that in common parlance, the business class seat would be referred to as a "lie-flat", the premium economy seat as a "recliner", and the regular economy seat as just a seat.

This is ultimately just how AA displays fares:


"Premium" is business or (where available) first class
"Premium Economy" is basically a wider recliner (basically the same seat as "domestic first class"/"shorthaul business class"; it's not extra-legroom economy (what AA markets, at least domestically, as "Main Cabin Extra": I suspect they don't use that marketing on longhaul because the benefits beyond the seat for MCE are available on all the economy fares))

Clicking "Premium" for a flight then shows business and first (if available) options.  "Premium Economy" will show the premium economy fare (as well as an upsell to business and first).  "Main" will show the basic economy and regular main cabin options (and for AA-operated flights, also offer the "Main Plus" bundle, which includes earlier boarding, an extra checked bag, and an extra-legroom seat).
In short, it's just a UI presentation thing on AA.  For instance, one can contrast this with Delta's 5 column layout:

Note that AA/British/Iberia/Aer Lingus and Delta/Virgin/Air France/KLM (as well as United/Lufthansa/Swiss/Brussels/Austrian) are respectively anti-trust immunized joint ventures, meaning (among other things) they set fares together, though each marketing carrier maintains their own fare class inventory (e.g. the BA marketed flight may have their discount bucket available while the AA marketed same-flight might not).
